# I need to highlight a text input when entry is correct

Tags: javascript

I would like to verify that what the user enters is exactly the same as the name value of the input. I have this working but I need for the input box to appear in green when it is. This is the code I have...

```js
function onKeyUp(el) {
    var update_value = el.value;
  var  inputValue = el.getAttribute('name');
  if(update_value == inputValue){
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.borderColor = "green";
  }
    if (update_value != inputValue) { // el.value is current value, inputValue is the default value
        $('[name="actionSave"]').removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
        $('[name="actionSave"]').addClass('disabled');
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got \ before quotes where it's not needed, also you should add what it's actually doing

Comment: sorry, forgot to remove the \...I'm outputting the script using PHP. (edited).

Answer (score 0):

I've got this partly working now...

```js
  function onKeyUp(el) {
    var update_value = el.value;
    var  inputValue = el.getAttribute('name');
  if(update_value == inputValue){
    // alert(update_value+"=="+inputValue);
    el.style.borderColor = "#66ff00";
  }
    if (update_value != inputValue) { // el.value is current value, inputValue is the default value
        jQuery('[name="actionSave"]').removeClass('disabled');
        
    } else {
        jQuery('[name="actionSave"]').addClass('disabled');
       
    }
}
```

When I type in the correct response, the text box turns green, however if I change it afterwards it does not change, it remains green. Is there a way to make it go back to the original color?